# How can AutoHotkey keep the order of the second column while sorting the numbers in the first column in descending order?

Tags: sorting, row, multiple-columns, autohotkey, word-frequency

Sorting with AutoHotkey by "CL" results in an optimal order in the word column (sorted alphanumerically from top to bottom: 1, 2, 10, 11, a, ä, aa, aä and so on).

```
$F3::
frequency_word :=
(
"2  bb
2   aa
1   b
1   a
3   bbb
3   aaa"
)
Sort, frequency_word, CL
; Sort, frequency_word, R
MsgBox, 262144, Note, % frequency_word
return
```

**Output**

```
1   a
1   b
2   aa
2   bb
3   aaa
3   bbb
```

If "Sort, frequency_word, R" is then used, the result is as follows:

```
3   bbb
3   aaa
2   bb
2   aa
1   b
1   a
```

Here, only the order of the numbers in the first column is to be sorted in descending order from top to bottom, without changing the order of the word column. It should then look like this:

```
3   aaa
3   bbb
2   aa
2   bb
1   a
1   b
```

With `R N` and

```
frequency_word := 
(
1   a
1   b
2   aa
2   bb
)`
```

the output is:

```
2   aa
2   bb
1   b
1   a
```

Here is a relevant source: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sort.htm.

Comment: Note that AHK isn't seeing two separate columns here, but rather, six rows and one column of strings. If you wish to have the output as you have shown in the last box, you will likely need to do more operations on the data or store the data in a different structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables created by regex can be stored in an array to sort the elements ([autohotkey.com/board/topic/93570-sortArray2](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/93570-sortArray2)).

Answer (score 0):

You can sort once by the second column (using the option P2), then sort by the first column

Comment: I have tried different ways with P2 and noticed that the first column is also sorted. So how should it be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Sort, frequency_word, R N
```

R: Sorts in reverse order (alphabetically or numerically depending on the other options).

The other option = **N** (numerically).